# Swift 3 incorrect initial UITableViewCell row height

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to programmatically design the layout of my custom UITableView cells. However, I get some strange behavior: despite setting the rowHeight, the first four rows are the default height, and then the rest are what I specified. This impacts the design of my cell, because I programmatically lay out labels based in part on the row height.

I initialize the tableview as follows:

```
func gameTableInit() {
    gameTableView = UITableView()
    gameTableView.delegate = self
    gameTableView.dataSource = self
    
    let navFrame = self.navigationController?.view.frame
    gameTableView.frame = CGRect(x: navFrame!.minX, y: navFrame!.maxY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - navFrame!.height - (self.tabBarController?.view.frame.height)!)
    gameTableView.rowHeight = gameTableView.frame.height/4 //HEIGHT OF TABLEVIEW CELL
    gameTableView.register(GameCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    
    self.view.addSubview(gameTableView)

}
```

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! GameCell
    print("height of cell: \(cell.frame.height)")
    var game = Game()
    game.awayTeam = "CLE"
    game.homeTeam = "GSW"
    cell.setUIFromGame(g: game)
    return cell
}
```

The print statement prints:

> height of cell: 44.0
>
> height of cell: 44.0
>
> height of cell: 44.0
>
> height of cell: 44.0

After some scrolling, it then prints the expected:

> height of cell: 166.75
>
> ...

I have created a custom tableview cell called GameCell

```
class GameCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        positionUIElements()
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    //on left
    var awayTeamAbbrev = UILabel()
    var awayTeamLogo: UIImage!

    //on right
    var homeTeamAbbrev = UILabel()
    var homeTeamLogo: UIImage!



    func positionUIElements() {
        //away team abbreviation is centered on upper left half of cell
        awayTeamAbbrev.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.minX, y: self.frame.minY, width: self.frame.midX, height: self.frame.height/4)
        awayTeamAbbrev.textAlignment = .center
        awayTeamAbbrev.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        //awayTeamLogo
        
        //home team abbreviation is centered on upper right half of cell
        homeTeamAbbrev.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.minY, width: self.frame.midX, height: self.frame.height/4)
        homeTeamAbbrev.textAlignment = .center
        homeTeamAbbrev.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    
        //homeTeamLogo
    
        self.contentView.addSubview(awayTeamAbbrev)
        self.contentView.addSubview(homeTeamAbbrev)
    }

    func setUIFromGame(g: Game) {
        awayTeamAbbrev.text = g.awayTeam!
        homeTeamAbbrev.text = g.homeTeam!
    }

}
```

I have tried many of the suggested answers online like calling layoutIfNeeded, but that didn't work anywhere I tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution: In my GameCell class, I overrided layout subviews:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    positionUIElements()
    self.awayTeamAbbrev.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.awayTeamAbbrev.frame.size.width
    self.homeTeamAbbrev.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.homeTeamAbbrev.frame.size.width
}
```

Answer (score 5):

While accepted answer can help in some cases I would like to share some other ways to fix this issue:

1. Check **Content Hugging Priority** of your cell's components (especially if you're using **stack views inside cell**)
2. In your cell add:

   ```
   override func didMoveToSuperview() {
   super.didMoveToSuperview()
   layoutIfNeeded()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

44 is defailt height for UITableViewCell in UITableView, try to override func

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

or return exact value, in your case 166.75

Comment: I want the height of the cell to vary based on the height of the device, so I tried setting the rowHeight member when initializing. However, every row should have the same height, which is why I avoided that function for performance reasons

Comment: Hmmm, I tried this method out of curiosity, and it still didn't work. Strange

Comment: Is that method called? There is option in inicialization of tableview - estimatedRowHeight

Comment: Yep, just verified heightForRow was called. But the behavior is still the same. Perhaps it is an Apple bug? This is my first time creating the tableviewcells completely in swift (usually I use IB), and my first time with this problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`. The `tableView` set the correct `cell` height after I attempt to scroll manually the content.

The `tableView` was inside on an `UIViewController`. The `dataSource` was applied on the `viewDidLoad` method.

I reloaded the `tableView` content using `tableView.reloadData()` inside the `viewWillAppear` and the problem was solve.